# Linq group by with parent object

Tags: c#, linq

How do I group so that I don't loose the parent identifier.

I have the following

```
        var grouped = mymodel.GroupBy(l => new { l.AddressId })
            .Select(g => new
            {
                AddressId = g.Key.AddressId,
                Quotes = g.SelectMany(x => x.Quotes).ToList(),
            }).ToList();
```

this returns

> { AddressId1, [Quote1, Quote2, Quote3...]}
>
> { AddressId2, [Quote12, Quote5, Quote8...]}

Now I would like to group these by Quote.Code and Quote.Currency, So that Each address has 1 Object-Quote (that is if all 4 quotes belonging to the address have the same Code and Currency). I would like the sum of Currency in that object.

This works, but I can't get how to add Address to this result:

```
        var test = grouped.SelectMany(y => y.Quotes).GroupBy(x => new { x.Code, x.Currency }).Select(g => new 
        {
            test = g.Key.ToString()
        });}
```

this gives compile error, whenever i try to add AddressId to result:

```
        var test1 = grouped.SelectMany(y => y.Quotes, (parent, child) => new { parent.AddressId, child }).GroupBy(x => new { x.Provider, x.Code, x.Currency, x.OriginalCurrency }).Select(g => new
        {
            test = g.Key.ToString(),
            Sum = g.Sum(x => x.Price)
        });
```

compiler error as well:

```
        var test1 = grouped.Select(x => new { x.AddressId, x.Quotes.GroupBy(y => new { y.Provider, y.Code, y.Currency, y.OriginalCurrency }).Select(g => new
        {
            addr = x.AddressId,
            test = g.Key.ToString(),
            Sum = g.Sum(q => q.Price)
        };
```

Comment: Can you show (as you did with addresses and quotes) the expected results?

Comment: If you want to sum `Currency`, what `Currency` did in groupping options? You should use only `Code` to group Quotes.

Comment: ok, i've got the currency sum working. but how do i add AddressId?

Comment: `Quotes = g.SelectMany(x => x.Quotes).GroupBy(x=>x.Code).Select(grp=>new{Code = grp.Key.Code, SumOfCurrency=grp.Sum(z=>z.Currency)})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do that this way:

```
    var grouped = mymodel.GroupBy(l => new { l.AddressId })
        .Select(g => new
        {
            AddressId = g.Key.AddressId,
            QuotesByCode = g.SelectMany(x => x.Quotes)
                            .GroupBy(x=>x.Code)
                            .Select(grp=>new
                              {
                                Code = grp.Key.Code,
                                SumOfCurrency=grp.Sum(z=>z.Currency)
                              }).ToList(),
        }).ToList();
```